# JavaFX Throws JRE Error: fatal error: Illegal threadstate encountered: 4

Tags: java, multithreading, intellij-idea, javafx, media

I am running a javafx application using Java 8 and I am getting this error; it isn't a standard error and does not point to any part of the code as a problem and instead gives the following output. I'm curious if anyone knows why this error is typically thrown/how to go about looking for a way to resolve it. Is this a code problem or jdk problem?

It does not occur on startup but after a while running different scenes. These scenes usually run without problems, but sometimes it will throw that error. The amount of time it takes changes and uses media that plays end to end (onEnd of one media the other starts, each has their own MediaView/MediaPlayer). I think the error usually happens when the media is changed from one video to the other/one video is relooping but I'm not too sure of this. Usually this often occurs without problem but somehow the same action will give an error other times. The error does not point to any code in the workspace but instead is simply text output.

ERROR INFO EXCERPT (full error on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/VdmTNqYB):

```
# Internal Error (safepoint.cpp:848), pid=27176, tid=0x000000000000950f
# fatal error: Illegal threadstate encountered: 4
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_312-b07) (build 1.8.0_312-b07)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.312-b07 mixed mode bsd-aarch64 compressed oops)

    Internal exceptions (10 events):
    Event: 31.193 Thread 0x000000011d83e800 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x000000079a26ffb8) thrown at [/System/Volumes/Data/ws/workspace/jdk-8u312/label/macosx-aarch64/type/b8/build/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 711]
    Event: 34.498 Thread 0x000000011d83e800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x000000079cf6cdf0) thrown at [/System/Volumes/Data/ws/workspace/jdk-8u312/label/macosx-aarch64/type/b8/build/hotspot/src/share/vm/interpreter/linkResolver.cpp, line 1287]
    Event: 34.602 Thread 0x000000011d83e800 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000007982b7ca8) thrown at [/System/Volumes/Data/ws/workspace/jdk-8u312/label/macosx-aarch64/type/b8/build/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 711]
    Event: 34.623 Thread 0x000000011d83e800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x00000007982c79b0) thrown at [/System/Volumes/Data/ws/workspace/jdk-8u312/label/macosx-aarch64/type/b8/build/hotspot/src/share/vm/interpreter/linkResolver.cpp, line 1287]
    Event: 41.638 Thread 0x000000011d83e800 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000007958cf640) thrown at [/System/Volumes/Data/ws/workspace/jdk-8u312/label/macosx-aarch64/type/b8/build/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 711]
    Event: 41.712 Thread 0x000000011d83e800 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x000000079c15e938) thrown at [/System/Volumes/Data/ws/workspace/jdk-8u312/label/macosx-aarch64/type/b8/build/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 711]
    Event: 42.382 Thread 0x000000011d83e800 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000007957104f0) thrown at [/System/Volumes/Data/ws/workspace/jdk-8u312/label/macosx-aarch64/type/b8/build/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 711]
    Event: 42.446 Thread 0x000000011d83e800 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x000000079a030b98) thrown at [/System/Volumes/Data/ws/workspace/jdk-8u312/label/macosx-aarch64/type/b8/build/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 711]
    Event: 43.292 Thread 0x000000011d83e800 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000007956a8870) thrown at [/System/Volumes/Data/ws/workspace/jdk-8u312/label/macosx-aarch64/type/b8/build/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 711]
    Event: 43.349 Thread 0x000000011d83e800 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x000000079af72300) thrown at [/System/Volumes/Data/ws/workspace/jdk-8u312/label/macosx-aarch64/type/b8/build/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 711]
```

Comment: You have posted part of a dump file that the JVM generates when it crashes. Hence I understand that your application is crashing intermittently. It looks like you are using OpenJDK 8 on MacOS. If I remember correctly, OpenJDK 8 does **not** include JavaFX. So which JavaFX are you using? Also, if, as you claim, the crashes are intermittent, then the problem cause is probably your code. Consider posting a [mcve].

Comment: Java 8 and JavaFX 8 are obsolete. For example. JavaFX 8 does not function on a modern M-series-based Mac (like you are trying to use).  Consider using Java/JavaFX 19+.  Instructions for usage are at [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io).  Additionally, you may have a threading issue in your code (e.g. modifying the JavaFX scene graph off of the JavaFX thread) or a garbage collected reference, so a fix it may need a code change from you, rather than just an upgrade.  Also, it is possible you are encountering a bug that was fixed in a more recent JavaFX version, so an upgrade might address your issue

Comment: I forgot to update this, I did end up fixing this by upgrading the java version, and fixed a memory leak issue. Not sure what fixed it but its good now ty for your responses.